why tuple couldn’t deduce std::tuple<void> template parameter C2641, tuple supports CTAD
import <tuple>;
import <iostream>;
import <string>;

using namespace std;

template<typename TupleType, int n>
class TuplePrintHelper
{
public:
    TuplePrintHelper(const TupleType& t)
    {
        TuplePrintHelper<TupleType, n - 1> tp{ t };
        cout << get<n - 1>(t) << endl;
    }
};

template<typename TupleType>
class TuplePrintHelper<TupleType, 0>
{
public:
    TuplePrintHelper(const TupleType&){}
};

template<typename T>
void tuplePrint(const T& t)
{
    TuplePrintHelper<T, tuple_size<T>::value> tph{ t };
};

int main()
{
    tuple t1{167, "Testaa"s,false, 2.3 }; //this lines show all err
    tuplePrint(t1);
}

visual studio2022 run show
C2641 tuple couldn’t deduce std::tuple template parameter , this shows tuple supports CTAD so what is the problem how to solve this problem
C2780   “std::tuple<_Types...> std::tuple(void)”: should input 0 ‌parameter，but Provided 4  parameters
C2780   “std::tuple<_Types...> std::tuple(std::tuple<_Types...>)”: should input 1 ‌parameter，but Provided 4
i learn from
https://github.com/carlesmartin85/procpp5e/blob/65aedda6a92745beca48a5041411465a33cdf4cd/code/c26_code/16_PrintTuple/02_PrintTupleSimplified.cpp
how to solve this problem, i want to CTAD not tuple<int, string_view, bool, double>
i try to update but still not work


Can't reproduce here after changing the imports to includes: https://godbolt.org/z/s4qYEYabP.  Can you paste the error messages in their entirety?

33line  tuple t1{167, "Testaa"s,false, 2.3 };  this lines  err
错误 C2641 无法推导“std::tuple”的模板参数 learnCPlus20 testtuple.cpp 33
错误 C2780 “std::tuple<_Types...> std::tuple(void)”: 应输入 0 个参数，却提供了 4 个 learnCPlus20 D:\Project\CPlus\two\thir\CPlus\learnCPlus20\testtuple.cpp 33
错误 C2780 “std::tuple<_Types...> std::tuple(std::tuple<_Types...>)”: 应输入 1 个参数，却提供了 4 个 learnCPlus20 D:\Project\CPlus\two\thir\CPlus\learnCPlus20\testtuple.cpp 33

Try changing the imports to #includes and see if you still get the same error.

Also what command are you using to build the project. And which compiler and compiler version.

i use visual studio 2022 C++20

import changes to #include , show the same err

Also, if you use c++latest, you can just do import std; and get everything at once.

Looks good here. Sidenote: tuple_size<T>::value is nicer written as tuple_size_v<T>

I just tried it in my local VS2022 (with #includes instead of imports) and it works fine. If you try this, what do you get then?

Note that TuplePrintHelper can be replaced by std::apply([](const auto&...args){ ((std::cout << args << std::endl), ...); }, t1); Demo

Version 17.12.0 Preview 1.0.
New Console project:
To use import,

Set C++ latest.
Set properties -> C++ -> scan source for Module Dependencies -> true




set C++ latest mean  Windows SDK update?

C++ language standard: latest. For sdk, I am using SDK v143.

friend   i  update the question the lastest result , it still not work  even as your advise  but  thank you for your advise

Can you share a sample project through GitHub? Since the code works fine locally, the problem may be related to the configuration of the project
